# Bash script returning [[: not found

Tags: bash, shell

my script is:

```
#!/bin/sh
if [[ $# -ne 1 ]] ; then
     echo 'Command line arguments are not equal to 1'
     exit 1
else
     NUMBER=$(grep -n "$1" /acct/common/filename | tr -dc '0-9')
     sed -n "$NUMBER"p /acct/common/filename | sed 's/,/ /g | sed "s/$1/ /g"
fi
```

The command in the else statement works when ran on its own in the script, but whenever I try to run the script the shell outputs

```
./findName.sh 2: ./findName.sh: [[: not found
```

Whenever I pass no arguments and then

```
./findName.sh: 2: ./findName.sh: [[: not found
expected result
```

Whenever I pass in an argument that should work

I'm not sure what's wrong as I am fairly new to shell scripting, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: get in the habit of copy/pasting your code into https://shellcheck.net and fixing any issues flagged. Good luck.]